# how can i confrim the JQuery is Ready in Chrome Extension App

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    ....
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches" : ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": [
                "main.js",
                "jquery-1.10.2.min.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_start",
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources":[
        "jquery-1.10.2.min.map"
    ]
}
```

here is my main.js:

```
// why this script is not work? I invoke JQuery when DOM is Ready...
$(document).ready(function(e){
    document.addEventListener('mouseup',function(e){
        var thisPageAsText=$(document).find('body').text();
        console.log(thisPageAsText);
    });
});
```

it seems to not work for me... Dose the content script not neet JQuery onReady?

Comment: "it seems to not work for me..." It works or not? If not, what is your issue??? Is document ready handler fired or not? Have you check your console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading jQuery *after* your main.js, so you are probably getting an error *'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'*.

You just need to reverse the order in which you load the files in your manifest:

```
        "js": [
            "jquery-1.10.2.min.js",
            "main.js"
        ],
```